# Does Value Loss in Actor Critic not decrease at all?

Tags: python, actor-critic-methods, loss

I am coding a problem with the Actor-Critic Method. The final loss is a summation of PolicyLoss and ValueLoss. The calculation of the PolicyLoss for each step is given at Equation Number 5 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.06347.pdf. And for Valueloss:

$V_t = \gamma \times V_{t+1} + r_t$

$\mbox{Valueloss} = \mbox{L}1\_\mbox{Loss}(Vt, Value)$

I checked that the PolicyLoss depends on this 'Value' as well. And PolicyLoss is decreasing, and so the parts of my AI model depending on the 'Value' are also updating. But I am seeing that the ValueLoss is not decreasing, however, the Total Loss which is the sum(ValueLoss, PolicyLoss) is decreasing.

I don't understand how to make the ValueLoss decrease, or if it should decrease at all. Because, the equation of ValueLoss suggests that it is like a 'chasing the tail' situation, so it may fluctuate.

Comment: Please, provide the correct link to the paper you're referring to. I believe that's `https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06347`.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited now

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I was right. The ValueLoss does not decrease as it IS a 'chasing the tail situation'. If I run the code with ValueLoss = a constant - Value instead of NextValue - Value, I see that the loss decreases.
A way out of it can be to calculate NextValue not for every run but for some runs.

Comment: Why would you want a "way out of it"? The reason the critic is "chasing its tail" is at least partially because the actor is improving, so the target values are *really* changing. What this does mean is that you should have different expectations when monitoring the critic loss compared to monitoring a supervised learning experiment.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right.